# Grabbing MySQL counts from loosely related tables with complex structure

Tags: mysql, sql, count, inner-join

MySQL here. I have the following data model in a Q&A database:

```
[questions]
===
question_id : PK           # ex: 12345
question_value : VARCHAR   # ex: 'What is your favorite food?'

[answers]
===
answer_id : PK              # ex: 23456
question_id : FK            # points to a questions.question_id
answer_value : VARCHAR      # ex: 'Pizza', 'French Fries', etc.

[user_answers]
===
user_answer_id : PK         # ex: 34567
question_id : FK            # points to a questions.question_id
user_answer_value : VARCHAR # ex: 'Pizza', 'French Fries', etc.
```

...where `[questions]` is a table containing all the questions I will ask users, `[answers]` is a table containing all the *possible* answers for each question, and `[user_answers]` are the *actual* answers users give for a particular question. So the application uses `[questions]` and `[answers]` to present a `user` with a question & possible answers, then the user selects one of those answers, and that result gets written to the `[user_answers]` table.

One **very important** thing to note is that the application will guarantee that there are never any "orphaned" `[user_answers]`, meaning, there will **always** be an `[answers]` record whose `[answer_value]` matches a `[user_answers.user_answer_value]`. So if there is a `[user_answers.user_answer_value]` in the database under a particular `question_id`, there will **always** be a matching `[answers.answer_value]`. Hence it is safe to match to the two "value fields" against each other in a query and not lose any data.

**I realize this is not a great data model.** But it is **critical** to point out that I simply cannot change it; its locked in and beyond my ability to make changes to, I'm simply stuck with it. And so unfortunately as much as I will want to, I cannot accept any answers that require changes to the data model.

Now then, I am trying to write a SQL query that -- for a given `question_id` -- returns the following columns:

1. the `answers.answer_id` as `id`
2. the `answers.answer_value` as `answer`
3. a **count** of how many `user_answers` existed for that particular `answers.answer_id`, using the value fields as a way of determining the match (i.e. "'Pizza' == 'Pizza'"), as `popularity`

So using the "favorite food" example from above, say that was the only question in the database, and the three possible answers were "Pizza", "French Fries" and "Cheeseburgers". Say 50 users had answered "Pizza", 65 users had answered "French Fries", and 12 users had answered "Cheeseburgers". Then the query would return results like so:

```
id      |     answer      |   popularity
==========================================
123     |   Pizza         |   50
456     |   French Fries  |   65
789     |   Cheeseburgers |   12
```

Important to note: if an answer has *never* been selected by any user yet, then its count should be zero (0).

My best attempt so far at this query is:

```
SELECT
  a.answer_id as id,
  a.answer_value as answer,
  count(ua.answer_id) as popularity
FROM
  answers a
INNER JOIN
  user_answers ua
ON
  a.question_id = ua.question_id
WHERE
  a.question_id = ?   # provided by application
  AND
  a.answer_value = ua.answer_value
```

However this doesn't look right to me. For one I don't believe an `INNER JOIN` is appropriate. I also believe I need to do a `GROUP BY` but I'm unsure of which table/column to group the count by.

Its important to note that in reality there will be hundreds of questions in this DB, each with 4 - 8 answers, and there will be hundreds (possibly thousands) of users providing answers, so its important that this query (which provides popularity counts for each question's answer) only include counts for user answers matching answers that are tied to the same "parent" question ID. **Can anyone spot where I'm going awry?**

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Queries surve a business purpose. If the query produces the expected results, then it is fit for the purpose. You auestion lacks the details as to what the purpose is! For examle: inner vs outer join - how do you need to handle an answer that no user selected? Group by vs no group by - the query seems to filter for a specific question, so do you need to return the number of answers per question or the number answersper answer per question?

Comment: `AND a.answer_value = ua.answer_value` looks unnecessry.

Comment: @D-Shih I did provide sample data and the expected result in the middle

Comment: Hi @Shadow for inner vs outer vs left, if an answer has never been selected by anyone, then I would expect the count for it to be zero (0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is as simple as:

```
SELECT answers.answer_id, answers.answer_value, COUNT(user_answers.user_answer_id)
FROM answers
LEFT JOIN user_answers ON answers.answer_value = user_answers.user_answer_value
WHERE answers.question_id = ?
GROUP BY answers.answer_id, answers.answer_value
```

The `LEFT JOIN` ensures that zero counts are included.

PS: The database design has some issues. I would rather change it to `user_answers(user_answer_id, answer_id)`.

Comment: Thanks @Salman A (+1) -- curious by what you mean in the notes there "not really needed". Is there a simpler way to write this query without the "FROM questions" portion?

Comment: I've removed it to eliminate confusion. It was there in case you need to use some column from questions table e.g. `WHERE questions.active = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for your requirement

```
select a.answer_id as id,a.answer_value as answer,count(user_answer_value) as popularity from user_answers ua 
join answers a on a.answer_id = ua.user_answer_value where a.question_id= 1 
group by a.answer_id, a.answer_value order by count(user_answer_value) desc
```